# How to write a database to a text file in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am working on a Spying application for my college project purpose. For that i have logged the Calls, Location and SMS of the device and stored them in a database. Now i want to export the contents of the database to a text file.. I tried the below code.

```
private void readAndWriteCallsData() {

    File dataBaseFile = getDatabasePath("DATABASE"); 

    File callDataFile = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory()+"/data/com.example.myapp/databases/"+"DATABASE");

    try {

        BufferedReader dbFileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(callDataFile));

        String eachLine;

        while((eachLine = dbFileReader.readLine()) != null)
        {

                Callslog.append(eachLine);
                Callslog.append("\n");

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

But that is not working... Please help me...

Comment: Your code has no Writers (All readers) !! Please explain what is not working?

Comment: Actually you can do this... But you just get binary data in text file.
May be you can just take your db file, rename it to proper text format and you will get what you need.

Comment: @AlekseyMaximus CODE PLEASE

Comment: Do you mean saving a database file onto a simple text file?

Comment: @hasan what kind of text format are you looking for ?

Comment: .txt format, i basicaly want to dump the .db file contents to a .txt format file

Comment: @hasan yes but what about the format ? You want the create / insert sql script ? Some raw data CSV style ?

Comment: i just want a way by which all the contents of the table get stored in a text file(my application can handle insertion n deletion of data,now i want that data to be stored in the text file)

Comment: Since you can insert and delete the data, you can read all of the data from the database too.  You can do this with a basic SQL query (which will return everything).  Then, you loop through the returned data, and output all the values into a text file.  I've done this to output to a csv.  Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: In your question you ask for EXPORT DATA from DB. Is that really what you want or you just want a simple copy/paste function of DB file? I can provide help in any case (yeah, call me bounty hunter);) , but I would like a precise question.

Answer (score 2):

You can encode the database file from binary stream to character stream by Base64, then decode the text when nessesary.

First find a Base64 library. You can use http://sourceforge.net/projects/iharder/files/base64/. There's only one file, "Base64.java".

Code example:

```
private void readAndWriteCallsData() {
    File callDataFile = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory()+"/data/com.example.myapp/databases/"+"DATABASE");
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(callDataFile);
        try{
            byte[] buf = new byte[512];
            int len;
            while((len = fis.read(buf)) > 0){
                String text = Base64.encodeBytes(buf, 0, len); // encode binary to text
                Callslog.append(text);
                Callslog.append("\n");
            }
        }finally{
            fis.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

To revert it, code like following:

```
private void revertCallsData() {
    File encodedCallDataFile; // get reference to the encoded text file
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(encodedCallDataFile));
        try{
            String line;
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                byte[] bin = Base64.decode(line); // decode each line to binary, you can get the original database file
            }
        }finally{
            br.close();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am a starter in Android. Can you please explain it with the code. The database file name is "DATABASE". Now how to write that data into a text file. **CODE PLEASE** Thank you :)

Comment: I tried the encoding part but still getting error...

`E/AndroidRuntime(16078): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.innolabs.spydroid.WriteFromDataBase@405464a0 with Intent { flg=0x4 cmp=com.innolabs.spydroid/.WriteFromDataBase (has extras) }: java.lang.NullPointerException
 com.innolabs.spydroid.WriteFromDataBase.readAndWriteDataseFiles(WriteFromDataBase.java:81)
E/AndroidRuntime(16078):  at com.innolabs.spydroid.WriteFromDataBase.onStartCommand(WriteFromDataBase.java:29)` I am getting error at CallsLog.append(text);

Comment: Paste the readAndWriteDataseFiles method pls, there must be wrong with it.

Comment: `private void readAndWriteDataseFiles() throws IOException {
     
     InputStream myinput = getAssets().open("DATABASE");

     String outfilename = Environment.getDataDirectory()+"/data/com.example.app/databases/"+ "DATABASE";
     
     System.out.println("outfilename"+outfilename);
     

     OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outfilename);

     byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
     int length;
     
     while ((length = myinput.read(buffer)) > 0)   {
     
      myoutput.write(buffer,0,length);
     }
     
     output.flush();
     output.close();
     myinput.close();
 }`

Comment: Check the above code.

And i found the other way... This link worked like charm - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9138601/exporting-database-file-as-text-or-xml-in-android..

Answer (score 2):

ok guys after a lot of hit and trial i finally found the solution, here is the code, i saved the functionality in a button.

```
final String SAMPLE_DB_NAME = "MyDBName.db";//database name
save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                    File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
                    FileChannel source=null;
                    FileChannel destination=null;
                    String currentDBPath = "/data/"+ "your package name" +"/databases/"+SAMPLE_DB_NAME;
                    String backupDBPath = SAMPLE_DB_NAME;
                    File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
                    File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);
                    try {
                        source = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                        destination = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                        destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
                        source.close();
                        destination.close();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Your database has been exported",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch(IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


            }


        });
```

**the database will be saved in /storage/emulated/0/**

Comment: this is not a db-dump, it's more like copying the db file, you still need sqlite application to open that file, right?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to export into a structered file format such as JSON or CSV. Here is my JSON exporter method. Maybe it helps

```
private static final String LOG_FOLDER = "/ExportFolder";
private static final String FILE_NAME = "export_file.json";

public static void exportMeasurementsJSON(Handler mHandler) {

    sendToastMessage("Export to JSON started", mHandler);

    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + LOG_FOLDER);
    if (!folder.exists())
        folder.mkdir();

    final String filename = folder.toString() + "/"
            + getLogFileName(".json");

    try {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename, false /* append */);

        // get the db
        SomeDateSource db = PIApplication.getDB();

        // Google Gson for serializing Java Objects into JSON
        Gson mGson = new GsonBuilder().create();

        Cursor c = db.getAllRows();
        if (c != null) {
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                fw.append(mGson.toJson(new DBEntry(c
                        .getString(1), c.getString(2), c
                        .getDouble(3), c.getLong(4))));
                fw.append('\n');
            }
            c.close();
        }
        fw.close();
        sendToastMessage("Export finished", mHandler);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        sendToastMessage("Something went wrong", mHandler);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

If you're interested I can also add my CSV exporter.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not that clear (Are you trying to copy the file to an alternative location or export the actual **data** from it?)

If you only wish to copy the file, you can copy the db file using the following method:

```
public static void copyFile(String sourceFileFullPath, String destFileFullPath) throws IOException
{
    String copyFileCommand = "dd if=" + sourceFileFullPath + " of=" + destFileFullPath;
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(copyFileCommand);
}
```

Simply call that method with your database file path (`/data/data/package_name/databases/database_name`) as `sourceFileFullPath` and your target file path as `destFileFullPath`. You can than use tools such as [`SQLite Expert`](http://www.sqliteexpert.com/) to view the content of the database on your PC/Laptop.

If your intention is to export the **data** from the database and store it in a text file (a CSV file or anything similar), then you should not read the database file content, and instead use the [`SQLiteDatabase`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) class to [`query`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) each table contents into a [`Cursor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) and iterate it to write each cursor row into a text file.

Answer (score 1):

You could export the entire db into your sdcard folder and then use SQLite manager to open and see it's content.

A Example is available here: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/export-sqlite-data-from-your-android-device/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete method for writing the Database in the SD Card:

```
/** 
     * Copy the app db file into the sd card
     */
    private void backupDatabase(Context context) throws IOException {
        //Open your local db as the input stream
        String inFileName = "/data/data/yourappPackageName/databases/yourDBName.db";
// OR use- context.getFilesDir().getPath()+"/databases/yourDBName.db";//
        File dbFile = new File(inFileName);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(dbFile);

        String outFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+SQLiteDataHelper.DB_NAME;
        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = fis.read(buffer))>0){
            output.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        //Close the streams
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        fis.close();
    }
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score -1):

One way to do this (I assume its a long procedure, easy one though), if you know the database and get all the tables and retrieve info from those tables. Since, we are talking about sqlite DBs, I assume it will be small.

```
SELECT * FROM dbname.sqlite_master WHERE type='table';
```