# Android save cursor/query results to sqlite DB file

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a method that queries a SQL table and saves the subset to a CSV file:

```
public void exportSQL(File outputFile, String c1) throws SQLException, IOException {

    csvWrite = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile));

    curCSV = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE col1 = '" + c1 + "'", null);

    csvWrite.writeNext(curCSV.getColumnNames());

    while (curCSV.moveToNext()) {
        String arrStr[] = {curCSV.getString(0), curCSV.getString(1), curCSV.getString(2),
                curCSV.getString(3), curCSV.getString(4), curCSV.getString(5),
                curCSV.getString(6), curCSV.getString(7), curCSV.getString(8)};

        csvWrite.writeNext(arrStr);
    }

    csvWrite.close();
    curCSV.close();
}
```

This works, however, I'd like to also save this query/subset as a sqlite (.db) file.

I've seen a number of questions about copying the entire database to another SQLite file, but haven't found anything containing a method for saving out only a subset of a table. In other words, I want to query a table to get a cursor, and then write the contents of that query/cursor to a `.db` file

Whats the correct way to do this in Java/Android?

There are a number of related questions on this, but they don't seem to cover this specific case. For example:

- [Copying data from one SQLite database to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359205/copying-data-from-one-sqlite-database-to-another). That question is about copying a table from one database to another (existing) database. Whereas I'm interested in querying/subsetting a table and saving that *subset* to a new (*non-existing*) database file
- [How to write a database to a text file in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461962/how-to-write-a-database-to-a-text-file-in-android). There are a number of questions like this one about saving the database to a text file, but I'd like my saved file to be a sqlite `.db` file, and to only contain my specific query results in a new table

Comment: The first link already has everything you need. SQLite treats a non-existing file as a new, empty database, and a SELECT query can do filtering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can simply save a query/subset, as a DB file that would be usable as a SQLite DB file, as a DB file holds other information e.g. it's master table.

What you could perhaps do is create a new, differently named empty database and then create the respective tables and populate them with the relevant data and finally save the new DB file.

An alternative could be to copy the DB file, open the copy as a database and then remove the components (rows tables) that you don't require to leave you with a copy with only the subset you require.

A third could be to make a copy of the original, whittle down the original, save a copy and then restore from the 1st copy.